# undefined reference to `libvlc_clock'

Tags: c, windows, gcc, libvlc

I'm trying to discover libVLC sdk in windows 7. Every time I compile the code, I'm getting this error

```
main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `libvlc_clock'
```

I've included the path. This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <vlc\vlc.h>
#include <vlc\libvlc.h>


int main()
{
    int64_t time = libvlc_clock();

    return 0;

}
```

and this is the line in prompt command in windows 7

```
gcc main.c -o test -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include"
```

Comment: You need to link the library, add `-lvlc -L<path to libvlc>` to your gcc command line.

Comment: `c:\Users\CroCo\Desktop\libVLC>gcc main.c -o test -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include"   -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\lib"
 -llibvlc`it tells me `libvlc.dll` is missing

Comment: @CroCo: read carefully - it's `-lvlc`.

Comment: @PaulR, I used it before and I got this error `c:/qt/qt5.2.1/tools/mingw48_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvlc
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: What files do you have in `VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\lib` ?

Comment: `libvlc.lib libvlc.la libvlccore.la libvlccore.lib` and a folder `pkgconfig`